# Trying to add a alphabetical word after a regexp mask

Tags: javascript, regexp-replace

I'm using a mask to transform the input text, in real-time, in this format: `000.000.000-00` and I need to add just one word after that: `000.000.000-00A`

I'm using this code, in regexp.

```
cpf=cpf.replace(/\D/g,"")
cpf=cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2")
cpf=cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2")
cpf=cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{1,2})$/,"$1-$2")
```

What's wrong with that code? I'm using `maxlength = 15`.

Comment: Your code doesn't really look like pure Java to me.  What is your language?  Also, what is the exact replacement logic here?

Comment: Is JavaScript with "RegExp" commands, making a mask for a input form... And the logic is to add a alphabetical word in the last character space, but only after insert all of the 11 numbers first. [11 numbers] + [1 alphabetical word]

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two entirely different languages. Please make sure you tag the correct language when asking questions.